# The constructor of a singleton class is called twice

Tags: c#, multithreading, singleton

I am reading a code, there is a singleton class like this:

```
class Employee
{
    public static readonly Employee Instance = new Employee();

    private Employee()
    {
        /* This messageBox shows different numbers */
        MessageBox.Show("Thread ID " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
```

The constructor of this class is called two times in same process without creating another Domain. The messageBox that is in constructor shows two different number. Is it possible or I'm wrong?

**NOTE:** I'm hosting my executable assembly in a c++ project, but there isn't something different and many large projects are working right.

Comment: @George87: Care to explain why? This is no problem as far as I am concerned.

Comment: He could encapsulate Employee Instance instead of allowing direct access but that should not matter much. Can you show code where you first attempt to get an instance of Employee?

Comment: @M7Jacks: like Employee.Instance.*

Comment: Are you sure that the message box you see one of those two times isn't from somewhere else?  It might help to make the message more distinctive to ensure that that isn't what's happening.

Comment: @Servy: Yes, I'm sure, I added this messageBox for debugging. In normal mode this is ok, but when I'm hosting it in a c++ that happens.

Comment: Is it possible that the C++ project is actually two (or more) processes, causing your .NET assembly to be loaded multiple times? Also, be sure to read the cautions here: http://csharpindepth.com/articles/general/singleton.aspx#cctor

Comment: Are you sure this happens in the same process? maybe you should print also the current process id in the message box to make sure.

Comment: @Roman: Yes I'm sure, I've done it.

Answer (score -1):

This fixed your problem, but too wrong implemetation of singleton.

```
class Employee
{
    private static Employee _instance;
    private static object syncRoot = new Object();

    public static Employee Instance
    {
        get
        {
            lock (syncRoot) 
            {
                if (_instance != null)
                    _instance = new Employee();
            }   
            return _instance;
        }
    }

    private Employee()
    {
        /* This messageBox shows different numbers */
        MessageBox.Show("Thread ID " + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
    }
}
```

Comment: There is nothing wrong with the OP's implementation.  This is adding more work/complexity without changing the functionality at all.